# Seeding microservices databases

Tags: microservices, event-sourcing

Given service A (CMS) that controls a model (Product, let's assume the only fields that it has are id, title, price) and services B (Shipping) and C (Emails) that have to display given model what should the approach be to synchronize given model information across those services in event sourcing approach? Let's assume that product catalog **rarely** changes (but does change) and that there are admins that can access data of shipments and emails very often (example functionalities are: B:`display titles of products the order contained` and C:`display content of email about shipping that is going to be sent`). Each of the services has their own DB.

**Solution 1**

Send all required information about Product within event - this means following structure for `order_placed`:

```
{
    order_id: [guid],
    product: {
        id: [guid],
        title: 'Foo',
        price: 1000
    }
}
```

On service B and C product information is stored in `product` JSON attribute on `orders` table

As such, to display necessary information only data retrieved from the event is used

**Problems**: depending upon what other information needs to be presented in B and C, amount of data in event can grow. B and C might not require the same information about Product, but the event will have to contain both (unless we separate the events into two). If given data is not present within given event, code can not use it - if we'll add a **color** option to given Product, for existing orders in B and C, given product will be colorless unless we update the events and then rerun them.

**Solution 2**

Send only guid of product within event - this means following structure for `order_placed`:

```
{
    order_id: [guid],
    product_id: [guid]
}
```

On services B and C product information is stored in `product_id` attribute on `orders` table

Product information is retrieved by services B and C when required by performing an API call to `A/product/[guid]` endpoint

**Problems**: this makes B and C dependant upon A (at all times). If schema of Product changes on A, changes have to be done on all services that depend on them (suddenly)

**Solution 3**

Send only guid of product within event - this means following structure for order_placed:

```
{
    order_id: [guid],
    product_id: [guid]
}
```

On services B and C product information is stored in `products` table; there's still `product_id` on `orders` table, but there's replication of `products` data between A, B and C; B and C might contain different information about Product than A

Product information is seeded when services B and C are created and are updated whenever information about Products changes by making call to `A/product` endpoint (that displays required information of all products) or by performing a direct DB access to A and copying necessary product information required for given service.

**Problems**: this makes B and C dependant upon A (when seeding). If schema of Product changes on A, changes have to be done on all services that depend on them (when seeding)

---

From my understanding, the correct approach would be to go with solution 1, and either update events history per certain logic (if Product catalog hasn't changed and we want to add color to be displayed, we can safely update history to get current state of Products and fill missing data within the events) or cater for nonexistence of given data (if Product catalog has changed and we want to add color to be displayed, we can't be sure if at that point in time in the past given Product had a color or not - we can assume that all Products in previous catalog were black and cater for by updating events or code)

Comment: In regards to `updating event history` - In event sourcing event history is your source of truth and should never be altered but only go forward. If events change you can use event versioning or similar solutions but when replaying your events up to a specific point in time the state of the data should be as it was at that point.

Comment: In regards to storing the data (schemas, etc..) for querying and fields being added/removed etc.. we used ourselves cosmosDB storing the data in JSON  as it is at that time. The only thing that needs versioning then is events and/or commands. You also need to update endpoint contracts and value objects containing the data responding to queries from a client (web, mobile, etc...). Older data not having a field will have a default value or blank, which ever suits the business but event history stays in tact and only moves forward.

Comment: @Nope by `updating event history` I mean: go through all the events, copying them from one stream (v1) into another stream (v2) to maintain consistent event schema.

Comment: As an aside, in the commerce/e-commerce realm, you may want to capture the price as stated given that pricing changes frequently. A price as displayed to the user may be different at the time the actual ordered is captured. There are any number of ways to solve the problem, but it is one that should be considered.

Comment: @CPerson yup - price could be one of attributes that is passed within the event itself. On the other hand, URL for the image can exist within event (representing intent of `display image at the point when purchase was made`) or can not (representing intent of `display current image as it within catalog`)

Answer (score 5):

Solution #3 is really close to the right idea.

A way to think about this: B and C are each *caching* "local" copies of the data that they need.  Messages processed at B (and likewise at C) use the locally cached information.  Likewise, reports are produced using the locally cached information.

The data is replicated from the source to the caches via a stable API.  B and C don't even need to be using the same API - they use whatever fetch protocol is appropriate for their needs.  In effect, we define a contract -- protocol and message schema -- which constrain the provider and the consumer.  Then any consumer for that contract can be connected to any supplier.  Backward incompatible changes require a new contract.

Services choose the appropriate cache invalidation strategy for their needs.  This might mean pulling changes from the source on a regular schedule, or in response to a notification that things may have changed, or even "on demand" -- acting as a read through cache, falling back to the stored copy of the data when the source is not available.

This gives you "autonomy", in the sense that B and C can continue to deliver business value when A is temporarily unavailable.

Recommended reading: [Data on the Outside, Data on the Inside](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf), Pat Helland 2005.

Comment: Yup, I completely agree to what you've written here and solution 3 is the goto solution I've applied, however, it's not the event sourcing approach, as, if we'll replay the events, we don't necessarily want to use current state of Product; we want to use the state as it was at the point of the event. Of course, this might be fine (dependant upon business requirement). If, however we want to keep track of changes to catalog, that requires event sourcing those as well, and dependant how much data that is, we might better falling back to solution 1.

Comment: I think you've got it w/ solution #3.  If you need replay consistency with the catalog, event source that too.  You only need to replay when you re-seed, which is probably at startup - once you're up you only need to look at new events, so the amount of data is probably not a real problem.  However, even then you have the option (if necessary) of using checkpoints, i.e. "here is the *state* as of event 1,000", so you take that and now you only have to replay event 1,001-to-current instead of the entire history.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I'd strongly recommend against option 2 because of the temporal coupling between those two service (unless communication between these services is super stable, and not very frequent). Temporal coupling is what you describe as `this makes B and C dependant upon A (at all times)`, and means that if A is down or unreachable from B or C, B and C cannot fulfill their function.

I personally believe that both options 1 and 3 have situations where they are valid options.

If the communication between A and B & C is so high, or the amount of data needed to go into the event is large enough to make it a concern, then option 3 is the best option, because the burden on the network is much lower, and latency of operations will decrease as the message size decreases. Other concerns to consider here are:

1. Stability of contract: if the contract of message leaving A changed often, then putting a lot of properties in the message would result in lots of changes in consumers. However, in this case I believe this to not be a big problem because:

   1. You mentioned that system A is a CMS. This means that you're working on a stable domain and as such I don't believe you'll be seeing frequent changes
   2. Since the B and C are shipping and email, and you're receiving data from A, I believe you'll be experiencing additive changes instead of breaking ones, which are safe to add whenever you discover them with no rework.
2. Coupling: There is very little to no coupling here. First since the communication is via messages, there is no coupling between the services other than a short temporal one during seeding of the data, and the contract of that operation (which is not a coupling you can or should try to avoid)

Option 1 is not something I'd dismiss though. There is the same amount of coupling, but development-wise it should be easy to do (no need for special actions), and stability of the domain should mean that these won't change often (as I mentioned already).

Another option I'd suggest is a slight variation to 3, which is not to run the process during start-up, but instead observe a "ProductAdded and "ProductDetailsChanged" event on B and C, wheneve there is a change in the product catalogue in A. This would make your deployments faster (and so easier to fix a problem/bug if you find any).

---

**Edit 2020-03-03**

I have a specific order of priorities when determining the integration approach:

1. What is the cost of consistency? Can we accept some milliseconds of inconsistency between things changed in A and them being reflected in B & C?
2. Do you need point-in-time queries (also called temporal queries)?
3. Is there any source of truth for the data? A service which owns them and is considered upstream?
4. If there is an owner / single source of truth is that stable? Or do we expect to see frequent breaking changes?

If the cost of inconsistency is high, (basically the product data in A need to be consistent as soon as possible with product cached in B and C), then youb cannot avoid needing to accept unavaibility, and make a synchronous request (like a web/rest request) from B & C to A to fetch the data. Be aware! This still does not mean transactionally consistent, but just minimizes the windows for inconsistency. If you absolutely, positively have to be immediately consistent, you need to rething your service boundaries. However, I **very** strongly believe this should not be a problem. From experience, it's actually extremely rare that the company can't accept some seconds of inconsistency, so you shouldn't even need to make synchronous requests.

If you do need point-in-time queries (which I didn't notice in your question and hence didn't include above, maybe wrongly), the cost of maintaining this on downstream services is so high (you'd need to duplicate internal event projection logic in all downstream services) that makes the decision clear: you should leave ownership to A, and query A ad-hoc over web request (or similar), and A should use event sourcing to retrieve all the events you knew about at the time to project to the state, and return it. I guess this may be option 2 (if I understood correctly?), but the costs are such that while temporal coupling is better than maintainance cost of duplciated events and projection logic.

If you don't need a point in time, and there isn't a clear, single owner of the data (which in my initial answer I did assume this based on your question), then a very reasonable pattern would be to hold representations of the product in each service separately. When you update the data for products, you update A, B and C in parallel by making parallel web requests to each one, or you have a command API which send multiple commands to each of A, B and C. B & C use their local version of the data to do their job, which may or may not be stale. This isn't any of the options above (although it could be made to be close to option 3), as data in A, B and C may differ, and the "whole" of the product may be a composition of all three data sources.

Knowing if the source of truth is has a stable contract is useful because you can use it to use the domain/internal events (or events you store in your event sourcing as storage pattern in A) for integration across A and services B and C. If the contract is stable you can integrate through the domain events. However, then you have an additional concern in the case where changes are frequent, or that contract of message is large enough that make transport a concern.

If you have a clear owner, with a contrac that is expected to be stable, the best options would be option 1; an order would contain all necessary information and then B and C would do their function using the data in the event.

If the contract is liable to change, or break often, following your option 3, that is falling back to web requests to fetch product data is actually a better option, since it's a much easier to maintain multiple versions. So B would make a request on v3 of product.

Comment: Yup, I agree. While `ProductAdded` or `ProductDetailsChanged` add complexity of tracking product catalog changes we need to keep that data synchronised between databases in some way, in case events are replayed and we need to access catalog data from the past.

Comment: @eithed I updated the answer to expand on some assumptions I made.

Answer (score 2):

[There are two hard things](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in Computer Science, and one of them is cache invalidation.

Solution 2 is absolutely my default position, and you should generally only consider implementing caching if you run into one of the following scenarios:

1. The API call to Service A is causing performance problems.
2. The cost of Service A being down and being unable to retrieve the data is significant to the business.

Performance problems are really the main driver.  There are many ways of solving #2 that don't involve caching, like ensuring Service A is highly available.

Caching adds significant complexity to a system, and can create edge cases that are hard to reason about, and bugs that are very hard to replicate.  You also have to mitigate the risk of providing stale data when newer data exists, which *can* be much worse from a business perspective than (for example) displaying a message that "Service A is down--please try again later."

From [this excellent article](http://udidahan.com/2012/08/28/data-duplication-and-replication/) by Udi Dahan:

> These dependencies creep up on you slowly, tying your shoelaces
>   together, gradually slowing down the pace of development, undermining
>   the stability of your codebase where changes to one part of the system
>   break other parts. It’s a slow death by a thousand cuts, and as a
>   result nobody is exactly sure what big decision we made that caused
>   everything to go so bad.

Also, If you need point-in-time querying of product data, this should be handled in the way the data is stored in the Product database (e.g. start/end dates), should be clearly exposed in the API (effective date needs to be an input for the API call to query the data).

Comment: Selecting option 2 as a default is really bad, especially given the context of microservices. If this is the default means of integration (rather than keeping a local copy), you are not considering the compounding effect of unavailability in your systems

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it definitely has it's place. But it's not a good/safe default when we're speaking about microservices, and this question is specifically asking about microservices (it's tagged with it).

Comment: Hm... I've not considered treating each update of the catalog as creating a new product. This means that old, unused products will never to be deleted, but I guess it's fine, thank you. I don't see the similarities to caching, but yes, you're correct on point-in-time querying

Comment: @eithed You will not need to create a new product each time.  see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension.  It's a very, very common way to accomplish this that does not require event sourcing.  Using event sourcing *just to solve this particular problem* as you suggested in another comment would be a classic example of overengineering .

Comment: @SavvasKleanthous "The network is reliable" is one of the fallacies of distributed computing.  But the response to that fallacy should not be "cache every bit of data from every service in every other service" (I realize that's a bit hyperbolic).  Expect that a service may not be available and deal with that as an error condition.  If you have a rare situation where Service A going down has a major business impact, then (carefully!) consider other options.

Comment: @SavvasKleanthous also consider (as I mentioned in my answer) that returning stale data in many cases can be *much* worse than throwing an error.

Comment: @PhilSandler just to clarify, we're not using event sourcing to just solve this problem. This problem arises due to event sourcing, and we can apply event sourcing to solve it; we don't need to.

Comment: @eithed I was referring to this comment: "If, however we want to keep track of changes to catalog, that requires event sourcing those as well".  In any case, you have the right idea--the Product service should be responsible for tracking changes over time, not the downstream services.

Comment: @Phil Sandler: using DDD you can allocate data where it is actually needed for processing and the need to store data locally is minimized. Your argument of storing the world does not apply at all.

Comment: In addition, storing data that you observe, while it has some similarities to caching, it does not exhibit the same problems. More specifically, invalidation is not needed; you get the new version of the data when it happens. What you experience is delayed consistency. However, even using web request there is a window of inconsistency (albeit a tiny one).

Comment: And lastly, again, within a distributed system, with multiple services running unavailability is compounding to really hit your SLO's. That's definitely something to avoid if possible.

Comment: I would very strongly suggest reading Hellands paper that @voice of unreason  linked to, which provides a lot of the groundwork around event driven architecture and data ownership

Comment: @SavvasKleanthous the way I read the question, it is NOT about denormalized read models that get built in real time from events and are intended to be eventually consistent--it's actually ABOUT caching.  VoiceOfReason's answer also reflects this interpretation, and you call it caching in your own answer.

Comment: @SavvasKleanthous In any case, my main point is not to try to solve problems that don't exist yet, especially with solutions that bring their own problems and risks.  Option 2 is the simplest solution and it should be the default choice *until such time as it doesn't meet business requirements*.  If you think choosing the simplest solution that can work is (as you put it) "really bad", then I think we just disagree.

Comment: You are not solving problems that do not exist yet. By using synchronous requests you directly and immediately, negatively impact your availability. And it has compounding behaviour. Also, storing a local projection from the source of truth of another service isn't complex or difficult. It is marginally more work than using http. For references, see Ian Coopers talks (who speaks about distributed systems and ECST)

Comment: But I agree that if your opinion is that in a microservice environment geometrically decreasing your availability is more preferred to a small amount of projection logic in some consumers, I don't think we could reach an agreement on this. I won't continue the discussion, and part in good spirits

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to simply say one solution is better than the other. Choosing one among Solution #2 and #3 depends on other factors (cache duration, consistency tolerance, ...)

**My 2 cents:**

Cache invalidation might be hard but the problem statement mentions that product catalog change rarely. This fact make product data a good candidate for caching

**Solution #1 (NOK)**

- Data is duplicated across multiple systems

**Solution #2 (OK)**

- Offers strong consistency
- Works only when product service is highly available and offers good performance
- If email service prepares a summary (with lot of products), then the overall response time could be longer

**Solution #3 (Complex but preferred)**

- Prefer API approach instead of direct DB access to retrieve product information
- Resilient - consuming services are not impacted when product service is down
- Consuming applications (shipping and email services) retrieve product details immediately after an event is published. The possibility of product service going down within these few milliseconds is very remote.